# Count categories changes in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, rules, counting

I have specific problem which is best described by a picture.

[image: image of the excel sheet]

*E1:G10 are rules for categories e.g. change from cat C to C will cause 1 hr delay.*

There are products which fall into category of a products **A**, **B** and **C**. Next to it you can find quantities of which they are produced. 
f you want to rebuild machine from cat. A to B etc. it will cost you time (ruling is described next to it).

I need to find a way how to determine time of rebuild. I did it manually and you can see it column **C**. However, I wish Excel would do it automatically. Later I am using data in solver.

Does anyone know solution to my problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the formula sumifs. 
For example the first category "C" with 1000 parts will change to category "A":
"=sumifs(G:G, E:E, A2, F:F, "A")"
I would also suggest you to put additional column with target category change and implement it to the formula.
Hope it helps.